# Youtube Data Studio, how to create calculated fields from two different data sources (such as two BigQuery tables)

Tags: google-bigquery, looker-studio

https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6390659

From the instruction video,"Create new calculated dimensions and metrics, which you can then use in your charts and controls", it shows how to create a calculated field from one data source.

But I need a calculated field that will be sum up of the values of fields from two different data sources (to be specific, two BigQuery tables).

I could not find anyway to do that. Except, I can create a BigQuery view sum up the value from two BigQuery tables in a BigQuery view. And then use this BigQuery View as my new data source. Not sure if this is the right and only way to do so.

Thanks for advices.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot reference more than one data source to create a calculated field in Data Studio. Pushing the calculation down to SQL/BigQuery is the correct approach. At least, that's how we do it too.